# Finding a path through a boolean matrix, with skipping

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix

Given an array `A` of boolean values in numpy, I'm looking to find a diagonal path (top-left to bottom-right) of true values from the top row to the bottom row. The trick is, I can accept offsets of three different types - vertical, horizontal, and both vertical & horizontal (which is to say - an interspersed falsey value.)  Each of the types of offset will have a threshold - a maximum number of acceptable instances.

So if `A` is:

```
0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Then the path `[0,2], [1,3], [2,4]` would satisfy the requirements, without using any offsets.

If we allow one of each type of offset, and if `A` is:

```
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

then `[0,2], [1,3], [2,5], [4,6]` satisfies the requirements for a path, using 1 of each of the three different kinds of offset.

I'm about to brute force this one.  Is there any graceful way of discovering these paths using `numpy`?  Or, failing that, any techniques I can use that would inject a note of grace?

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps this should be tagged with [algorithm] too: a huge chunk of your problem is determining a good algorithm. Your problem seems hard: already the original is a percolation problem, and adding a finite global number of faults doesn't make it any simpler:) Something with growing your ones with binary dilation comes to mind, but the *global* constraint on the number of offsets makes it even harder.

Comment: Added the algorithm tag.  Good idea.

Comment: Throwing in an idea - Do dilation, subtract from the original array, store as `A`. Now, get all paths between start and stop pts on the dilated image and detect which paths have exactly three pts from `A`. If you need three offsets from each of the three groups, you might have to ID each item in `A` based on the groups. For the paths, you can use `networkx` module.

Comment: Are the offsets always of length 1 (in max metric) or can they be of any length?

Comment: @NicoSchertler If the threshold for a particular offset is greater than one, the instances of that offset could be consecutive.

Comment: Yes, the question was if jumping directly from the top row to the bottom row counts as a single offset. Apparently not. But can you define exactly what the requirements are? I'm still not very sure about that. Especially how you come up with the jump counts in the second example.

Comment: What I've called an offset is a single skip.  Where a non-offset transition would be add (1,1) to the previous place, an offset transition would add (1,2), (2,1) or (2,2).   And if the thresholds allow, there can be more than one in a row.